# File Upload Not working in update Panel I also tried triggers but it also not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

File Upload Not working in update  Panel I also tried triggers but it also not working KINDLY RESOVE MY ISSUE

***<%@ Page Title="Pharmacy Orders" Theme="DefaultTheme" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="OnlinePharmacyOrders.aspx.cs" Inherits="Forms_Online_OnlinePharmacyOrders" %>

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH_Header" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH_Menus" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH_Content" runat="Server">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_PharmacyOrder" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" UpdateMode="Conditional">
       <ContentTemplate>
 <ProgressTemplate>
                    <div class="UpdateProgress">
                        <img src="../../App_Themes/DefaultTheme/Images/loading.gif" alt="" class='loadingImg' />
                    </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>

       <ajax:TabContainer ID="TC_PharmacyOrders" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="true">

                               <ajax:TabPanel ID="TP_Detail" runat="server" TabIndex="1" Visible="false">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Detail
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ContentTemplate>


                        <asp:Panel ID="Pnl_UpdateTrackingNo" runat="server" DefaultButton="Btn_UpdateTrackingNo" Visible="False">

                            <table class="tblListing">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="Heading">Order Detail  (Update Tracking / Status) </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Order No</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_OrderNoT" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Ordered Placed By
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_OrderByT" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Contact No
                                    </td>
                                    <td>

                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_ContacTNoT" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Invoice No
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_InoviceNoT" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Delivery Charges
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_DeliveryChargesT" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Invoice Amount
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_InvoiceAmountT" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Delivery Address
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_DeliveryAddressT" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Pharmacy  Remarks
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_PharmacyRemarksT" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Status
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="Cmb_StatusT" Filter="StartsWith" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" Width="180px" BorderWidth="1px" Skin="Office2010Silver">

                                            <Items>
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Pending" Value="1" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Dispatched" Value="2" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Cancelled" Value="3" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Received by Customer" Value="4" />
                                                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Returned" Value="4" />

                                            </Items>


                                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Tracking No (if Any)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxBx_TrackingNoT" runat="server" ValidationGroup="T"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV_TrackingNoT" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxBx_TrackingNoT" Display="None" ErrorMessage="* Required" ValidationGroup="T"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="RFV_TrackingNoT_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="RFV_TrackingNoT">
                                        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="RFV_TrackingNo">
                                        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Button ID="Btn_UpdateTrackingNo" runat="server" SkinID="SaveSkin" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="T" Width="100px" OnClick="Btn_UpdateTrackingNo_Click" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>



                            </table>



                        </asp:Panel>



                        <asp:Panel ID="Pnl_SaveOrder" runat="server" DefaultButton="Btn_SaveOrder" Visible="False">

                            <table class="tblListing">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="Heading">Order Detail</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Order No</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_OrderNo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Ordered Placed By
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_OrderBy" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Contact No
                                    </td>
                                    <td>

                                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl_ContacTNo" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Invoice No
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxBx_InvoiceNo" runat="server" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV_InvoiceNo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxBx_InvoiceNo" Display="None" ErrorMessage="* Required" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="RFV_InvoiceNo_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="RFV_InvoiceNo">
                                        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Prescribed By (Consultant/Dr)

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxBx_ConsultantName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV_ConsultantName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxBx_ConsultantName" Display="None" ErrorMessage="* Required" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="VCE_ConsultantName" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="RFV_ConsultantName">
                                        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Tracking No (if Any)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxBx_TrackingNo" runat="server" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV_TrackingNo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxBx_TrackingNo" Display="None" ErrorMessage="* Required" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="RFV_TrackingNo_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="RFV_TrackingNo">
                                        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Delivery Charges
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxBx_DeliveryCharges" CssClass="numeric" runat="server" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV_DeliveryCharges" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxBx_DeliveryCharges" Display="None" ErrorMessage="* Required" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="RFV_DeliveryCharges_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="RFV_DeliveryCharges">
                                        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Invoice Amount
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxBx_InvoiceAmount" runat="server" CssClass="numeric" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV_InvoiceAmount" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxBx_InvoiceAmount" Display="None" ErrorMessage="* Required" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="RFV_InvoiceAmount_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="RFV_InvoiceAmount">
                                        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Delivery Address
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxBx_DeliverAddress" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Width="400px" Rows="6" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV_DeliverAddress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxBx_DeliverAddress" Display="None" ErrorMessage="* Required" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="RFV_DeliverAddress_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="RFV_DeliverAddress">
                                        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Pharmacy  Remarks
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxBx_PharmacyRemarks" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Width="400px" Rows="6" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV_PharmacyRemarks" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxBx_PharmacyRemarks" Display="None" ErrorMessage="* Required" ValidationGroup="E"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="RFV_PharmacyRemarks_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="RFV_PharmacyRemarks">
                                        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">Status
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Status" runat="server" Width="200px">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Dispatched" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Received" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>





                            </table>





                        </asp:Panel>
                        <table class="tblListing">
                            <tr>
                                    <td class="Heading" colspan="2">Upload Invoice
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">&nbsp;Upload Invoice</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="File_Uploader" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td class="shade">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Button ID="Btn_SaveOrder" runat="server" SkinID="SaveSkin" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="E" Width="100px" OnClick="Btn_SaveOrder_Click" Height="26px" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                          <table class="tblListing">


                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: center">
                                        <asp:Image ID="Img_Invoice" runat="server" AlternateText="Invoice" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        <table class="tblListing">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" class="Heading">Prescription
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                                    <asp:Image ID="Img_Prescription" runat="server" AlternateText="Prescription" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="TR_Move" runat="server">
                                <td runat="server">
                                    <asp:Button Width="100px" ID="Btn_Previouse" runat="server" Text="&lt;&lt; Previouse " CausesValidation="False" SkinID="ShowAllSkin" OnClick="Btn_Previouse_Click" />
                                </td>
                                <td runat="server">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Btn_Next" Width="100px" runat="server" Text="Next &gt;&gt;" CausesValidation="False" SkinID="ShowAllSkin" OnClick="Btn_Next_Click" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        &nbsp;
                    </ContentTemplate>

                </ajax:TabPanel>
            </ajax:TabContainer>


        </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>

            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Btn_SaveOrder" />

        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH_Footer" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>***
```

Comment: its been long time since i have used webforms, but i don't think Update Panels supported File uploads.

Comment: @WaqarAhmad are you getting error?